# How can i use the same class with differents mapDispatchToProps - Best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have been using react and redux for a few weeks and i was wondering how you would use the same Component with different implementation of mapDispatchToProps. I am seeking for the best practice.

So let's say i have a form component like this one:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class SimpleForm extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.props.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.label}>
          {`${this.props.label} :`}
          <input
            id={this.props.label}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to connect this component to an action in my store.

I can do that easily with :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    handleSubmit: event => dispatch(handleSubmit(event)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SimpleForm);
```

So i know how to connect a specific action to my component.

My question here is what is the best practice to reuse this component with other redux actions. It would mean here that i would be able to use SimpleForm and connect it before using it to a specific action.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: do you mean that you have multiple action creators and you want to use them all in this components ??? if it is so , say yes to give you the proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways that come to mind. The first is that you define all the action creators ahead of time in you `mapDispatchToProps` for all your use cases. This is the simpler approach, but may be more limiting for you.

The second way that comes to mind is to use the `ownProps` argument that gets passed to `mapDispathToProps`.

something like this.

```
import * as allActions from "./file";

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    'ownProps.functionName': () => dispatch(allActions[ownProps.functionName]),
});
```

`ownProps` is what you actually pass in when you use this component.

As in `<Form functionName={myAction} />`

This does seem a little clunky and convoluted, but if this is what you need, I think it can work.